# What are inverted pairs in quicksort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have a hw problem involving runtime of quicksort that states the runtime is Big-Theta(x + n) where n is the size of the input and x is the number of inverted pairs. But, what is an inverted pair? and how do I tell how many there are in an unsorted array?

Comment: From context, I would assume that it means the number of pairs of numbers that are in the wrong order, e.g. n[i] = 10 and n[i+1] = 5 would be an inverted pair, assuming you're sorting smallest to largest.

Comment: It just means the number of pairs *i,j* such that *i < j*, but *input[i] > input[j]*  That's the number of adjacent element swaps required to sort *input*